# WebDriver. Python. I want to store one of the option of drop-down menu by value as text, how to do it?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to store one of the option of drop-down menu by value as text. I select random option by next Python script:

```
#Random select option by value
assignJob = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('job[job_title]'))
jobValue = str(randint(1, 6))
assignJob.select_by_value(jobValue)
```

HTML code:

```
<select name="job[job_title]" class="formSelect valid" id="job_job_title">
  <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="1">Customer Service</option>
  <option value="4">QA Engineer</option>
  <option value="3">QA Manager</option>
  <option value="2">SDET</option>
  <option value="5">Software Developer</option>
  <option value="6">Software Development Manager</option>
</select>
```

Error when I assign variable storedJob = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#job_job_title option[value=jobValue]").text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 62, in <module>
    storedJob = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#job_job_title option[value
=jobValue]").text
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriv
er\remote\webdriver.py", line 365, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriv
er\remote\webdriver.py", line 681, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriv
er\remote\webdriver.py", line 164, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriv
er\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'no such element\n
 (Session info: chrome=32.0.1700.102)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.241075,p
latform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86)'
```

Code:

```
assignJob = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('job[job_title]'))
jobValue = str(randint(1, 6))
assignJob.select_by_value(jobValue)
storedJob = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#job_job_title option[value=jobValue]").text
print storedJob
```

Another Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 63, in <module>
    storedJob = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(jobValueSelector).text
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriv
er\remote\webdriver.py", line 365, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriv
er\remote\webdriver.py", line 681, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriv
er\remote\webdriver.py", line 164, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriv
er\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: u"invalid elem
ent state: Failed to execute query: '#job_job_title option[value=2]' is not a va
lid selector.\n  (Session info: chrome=32.0.1700.102)\n  (Driver info: chromedri
ver=2.8.241075,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a CSS selector, to locate that option and ask selenium to return its text.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#job_job_title option[value=2]").text
```

Replace `2` with the variable `jobValue` for you specific scenario.

**EDIT**

`jobValue` is a variable(str), you cannot directly pass a variable in Python.

```
jobValueSelector = "#job_job_title option[value='%s']" %jobValue
storedJob = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(jobValueSelector).text
print storedJob
```

Comment: Well `jobValue` is a variable, string interpolate it in.

Comment: I know but it doesn't help. Check my code please, I've added it below error.

Comment: You have not string interpolated, you literally replaced `2` with `jobValue`. Check the update to my answer.

Comment: Did you try what I wrote in my edit? Copy paste that code and try it, and respond back with the error message

Comment: Of course I did, it says: '#job_job_title option[value=2]' is not a valid selector. And a lot of mess... I've updated question. Check it.

Comment: How can I communicate with you? I'd like to show to you full code (it's not very big).

Comment: I have made a small edit again, included single quotes, just try this bit of code again

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot!!! It works fine! ))  But I also have another problem with logout xDD

Comment: Awesome! That it works. You could upvote and mark this answer as the solution and create another question. To mark this as the solution you can read here
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 1):

The piece of code below is in Ruby.. I think Python and Ruby is almost the same.

```
select_list = driver.find_element(:id, 'job_job_title')
options = select_list.find_elements(:tag_name, 'option')
index = rand(1..options.count) # Get random number from index 1 to options.count
my_variable =  options[index]
```

Let me try my skill in Python (not tested)! :)

```
select_list = driver.find_element_by_id("job_job_title")
options = select_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
index = randint(1, len(options)) 
variable = options[index]
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but I don't know syntax of Ruby. Let me try your code on Python... :)